# Can gateway handle different protocols?

Tags: networking, device, network-protocols

Can gateway(network device) handle different protocols. I know that it is used to connect dissimilar networks. What type of dissimilarity does it include?

Answer (score 0):

The term Gateway is a very broad term. In Networking a Gateway is typically a device that sits between two network domains or at the entrance to a domain and may handle protocol translations, perform address translations, filter traffic, terminate sessions and much more.

An IP Router for example in some cases is named as a Gateway as it connects the local subnet to the rest of the network - hence the term 'default gateway' you can see on every PC IP settings.

To answer your first Q - a gateway in many cases would handle different protocols.